# How to get every nth line into different arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, while-loop

I need to create a program that seperates every name and each type of scores the students are taking.(test finals etc) The file I'm reading looks like this:

```
*Puckett, Karen
10 10 9.5 10 10 8 9.5 10 10 10 9 10 10 10 0
4 3 5 3 5 2 3 2 1.5 1 5 3.5
17.5 24 22 23.5 22 23
90 91
96
*
```

It repeats for a total of 16 students. The method I created for the name looks like this so far:

```
public static String[] name(String output, int i) {
String[] names = new String[16];
String name = nulll
while (i<16) {
name = ???;
names[i] = name;
i++;
}
return names;
}
```

If i find what I need to set the name variable to I think I will be able to repeat them for each method and finish the rest of the requirements. variable i starts at 0 and comes from the main method and output is the string I made from the text file I'm reading from, and also comes from the main method.

Comment: You should include a tag for which language this is. Looks like Java?

Comment: Crap forgot, Thanks!